# Stuck into Ranking algorithm

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, ranking

I'm stuck into an algorithm that I'm working on a few days. It's something like this:

I have lots of posts, and people may like or dislike them. In a scale from 0 to 100, the algorithm shows the most liked posts first. But when new posts arrives, they haven't any score yet, so they get to the end of this ranking. What I did: when a post haven't any vote, I put an default score (for example, 75).

When the first user likes this new post, it get the total score (100), but when the user dislike it, it goes to the end of the list (score 0).

What can I do to achieve this ranking for liked posts based on the total number of users who liked it?

If I wasn't clear enough, please tell me

Any help will be appreciated.

What I had done so far:

```
select id,(
(select cast(count(1) as float) from posts p1 where p1.id = p.id and liked = 1) /  
(select cast(count(1) as float) from posts p2 where p2.id = p.id)
)*100 AS value
from posts p  
group by id
```

Comment: There are writeups of this sort of thing on the web e.g. http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help, but I had solved my problem this way:

I maintained the original query with an additional clause

```
select id,(
(select cast(count(1) as float) from posts p1 where p1.id = p.id and liked = 1) /  
(select cast(count(1) as float) from posts p2 where p2.id = p.id)
)*100 AS value,
(select count(1) from posts p3 where p3.id = p.id) as qty
from posts p  
where qty > 5
group by id
```

So, if a new post comes in, it will have the default value assigned until the fifth user rate it. If the content is truly bad, it goes to the end of the list, otherwise it will stay on top until other users rate it down.

May not be the perfect solution but worked for me

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this problem is to subtract a standard error from the estimated values.  I would treat the variable in question as the proportion of likes among all responses to the post.  The standard error is:  sqrt(plikes * (1 - plikes)/(likes + notlikes)).

In SQL, this would be something like:

```
select id,
       (avg(liked*1.0) - sqrt(avg(like * 1.0) * avg(1.0 - like) / count(*))) as like_lowerbound
group by id;
```

Subtracting one standard error is somewhat arbitrary, although there is a statistical basis for it.  I have found that this works pretty well in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly what you want but in any case, here it goes my answer. A ranking system may be based on the average of the positive votes (likes), this means, rank = number_of_likes / (number_of_likes + number_of_dislikes).

In SQL, you have something like this:

```
SELECT id, (likes/(likes + dislikes)) as rank FROM posts order by rank desc;
```

You can multiply by 100 if you need the result to be between [0, 100], instead of [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

I will write two query using union all instead of going into so complication .

```
---First query to select fresh post 
--also include one column which can be use in order by clause
-- Or you can make your own indication
Select col1,col2 .......,1 Indicator from post where blah blah
Union all
--Second query to select most populare
Select col1,col2 .......,2 Indicator from post where blah blah
```

Then in front end you easily identify and do filtering .

```
Also it is easy to maintain and quite fast .
```